# How to block PHP content inside HTML code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to block any PHP code inside a HTML code?

I have a function in my application where user create a HTML page, with HTML code, Javascript code and CSS code. But I can't allow him to save any PHP code, because this content will be saved in a file and loaded in the server.

```
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is allowed</h1>
        <?php echo "DELETE THIS LINE"; ?>
    </body>
    <script>
         console.log("THIS IS ALLOWED");
    </script>
</html>
```

I need to comment or delete the PHP code, but i don't have idea how to do that.

Comment: I will try with str_replace

Comment: I think str_replace worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the file and the PHP won't execute (it will be in the HTML source as an unknown HTML tag but not executed).  Just read it and output:

```
$output = file_get_contents("/path/to/file.html");
echo $output;
//or
readfile("/path/to/file.html");
```

Or if you want to include it, then comment the PHP before writing to the file (it will be a comment in the HTML source):

```
$output = str_replace(['<?php', '?>'], ['<!--', '?>'], $html);
file_put_contents("/path/to/file.html", $output);

//where you want to use it
include("/path/to/file.html");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the php function `htmlspecialchars()` to sanitize user's code. See doc [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: That will wreck the HTML as well.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() not worked.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, but then the `echo` will give it back its syntax without executing it.

Comment: But they state that they want HTML, CSS and JavaScript to work correctly.

Comment: @AbraCadaver right it's true